# ScriptBlock - Using Out Of Scope Functions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
function F2([String]$var2) {
    ...
}

function F1([String]$var1) {
    ...
    F2 $var2
    ...
}

...

while ($i -le $count) {
    F1 "dir$i"
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:F1} -ArgumentList @($i)
    $i = $i + 1
}
```

In the above snippet, I'd like to start a job and run `F1` for every iteration of the `while` loop. Although what's defined in `F1` works fine, the call by `F1` to `F2` doesn't seem to go through when done via the scriptblock because `F2` is out out of scope. Is there any alternative that I can use here?